# How do I recursively download all the mediawiki markdown sources from a private wiki

Tags: markdown, backup, mediawiki

My server provider is killing my server and forcing me onto a new one.  The old mediawiki is version 1.13.  The new one is 1.32, so there will have to be a lot of hand massaging the content into shape for the new server.  I have about a dozen different mediawiki databases being run on the old server and know all my top URLs.  There is a boatload of content and I have tried doing it by hand for about 2 days now.

I am hoping that there is a tool to open each top page separately, go into edit mode, fetch the markdown, store it in a file (just numbered would be okay (e.g. markdown1.wiki) fetch the image files and store them too.  Also, it would be extra useful for the tool to be able to authenticate login to access pages forbidden for public view.  It would be best if the page name were modified to be a proper filename and use that instead of numbered wiki files.

Then, find all links on the page and download those (e.g. markdown2.wiki, ... markdownN.wiki), and continue recursively until the entire site has been spanned.

I only have about a week or two at most before the entire task must be done.

Is there any such tool out there?  Anything even close?  I have looked a lot, and things like wget will only fetch the final HTML markup.  If nothing else works, that will have to be my fallback.

Comment: BTW, I tried to use dumpBackup.php in the maintenance directory, and it complained about DIR being missing.  I tried to fix it but didn't succeed.  It sounded like just what I needed, but I do not know whether the XML reflects the markdown or the HTML produced.

Comment: Something else instead that might help - dumpgenerator.py from https://code.google.com/archive/p/wikiteam/wikis/NewTutorial.wiki

Comment: Thank you.  That looks promising.  I will report back on whether it works for my problem.

Comment: I don't think this is relevant to your question, but MediaWiki has its own markup format that's quite different from Markdown.

Comment: I am super-familiar with mediawiki markdown.  I've written a number of my own wiki engines.  But thatnk you for the input.